# How can I animate a smile into a frown by clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript

How can i morph an image by clicking on a button? This is a schools assignment. I need to draw a smile (which i did) and animate the smile into a frown by clicking on a button.

My prof told us to "Create a drawMouth function that takes 2 arguments, bx and by, and sets the mouth path using the values passed in. Call the function in your button event listener."

Apart from not understanding his instruction, i am also 100% sure that he did not teach animations yet!! So far the button I created can toggle between the smile and frown, but i have no idea how to make the animation.

```
 var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById("mySVGCanvas")); 

    // smile
    var smile1 = paper.path("M 300,200 Q 400,300 500,200 Z");
    smile1.attr({
        'stroke': "blue",
        'stroke-width': 5
    });


    // button
    var button1 = paper.circle(100, 300, 50);
    button1.attr({
        'fill': "#c64ee4",
        'stroke':"#c64ee4",
        'stroke-width': 1
    });

    //0=success & smile, 1=rage & frown
    var myState = 0;

    //toggle
    button1.node.addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log("this part is working...");
        if (myState === 0){
            myState = 1;
            //toggle image
            var image1 = paper.image("https://tromoticons.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/y-u-no.png?w=350&h=300&crop=1", 10, 10, 100, 100); 
            //toggle smile-frown
            smile1.attr({
                path: "M 300,200 Q 400, 100 500, 200 Z"
            });

        } else{
            myState = 0;
            //toggle image
            var image1 = paper.image("http://www.sherv.net/cm/emoticons/trollface/success-troll-smiley-emoticon.png", 10, 10, 100, 100); 
            //toggle smile-frown
            smile1.attr({
              path: "M 300,200 Q 400,300 500, 200 Z"
            });
        }

        });
```

Comment: you could have some intermediate paths, and switch from those, one by one, eg smile -> half-smile -> neutral -> half-frown -> frown, etc

Comment: a vertical rotation might do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can create an animation with the javascript `setInterval(...)` function. This function executes code at a given time interval until it's terminated.

I.E. something like :

```
//toggle
var myInterval;
var theTime = 0;
var endTime = 1000;
button1.node.addEventListener('click', function(){

        //toggle image
        var image1 = paper.image("https://tromoticons.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/y-u-no.png?w=350&h=300&crop=1", 10, 10, 100, 100);

        //toggle smile-frown
        myInterval = setInterval(function() {
            smile1.attr({
                var smilePercent = myState === 1 ? theTime / endTime : 1 - theTime / endTime;
                // here set your 'path' attribute as a function of 'smilePercent'
            });
            theTime += 50;
            if (theTime >= endTime) {
                theTime = 0;
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
        }, 50);
        myState = myState === 1 ? 0 : 1;
    } 
});
```